# How can I add engineering-style dimensioning to graphics?

Tags: graphics

Is there any specific function for this type of presentation formed by the code $dim1$, $dim2$ and $dim3$?

Barra

```
p1 = {0, 0} (*Ponto1 de apoio da barra*);p2={1,0}(*Ponto2 de apoio da barra*);
barra = Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], Line[{p1, p2}]}];
```

Suporte1

```
hsup =.08 (*Altura do suporte*);
sup1 = 
  Graphics[
    {GrayLevel[0.34], Thickness[0.005] (*Espessura do Suporte*), 
     Line[
       {{p1[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}, {p1[[1]] + hsup/2, -hsup}, 
        p1,{p1[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}}]}];
```

Suporte2

```
sup2 = 
  Graphics[
    {GrayLevel[0.34], Thickness[0.005] (*Espessura do Suporte*),  
     Line[
       {{p2[[1]]  - hsup/2, -hsup}, {p2[[1]] + hsup/2, -hsup},
        p2, {p2[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}}]}];
```

Força

```
posx = 0.2*(p2[[1]] - p1[[1]]) (*Comprimento da barra*);
f1 = 
  Graphics[
    {Red, Thickness[0.02] (*Espessura da seta*), 
     Arrowheads[hf1/3], Arrow[{{posx, hf1 = 0.25},{posx,p1[[2]]}}]}];
```

Dimensão L

```
dim1 = 
  Graphics[
    {Thickness[0.003], 
     Line[{Offset[{0, off1 = 20}, p1], Offset[{0, off2 = 400}, p1]}]}];
dim2 = 
  Graphics[
    {Thickness[0.003], 
     Line[{Offset[{0, off1}, p2], Offset[{0, off2}, p2]}]}];
dim3 = 
  Graphics[
    {Thickness[0.003], Arrowheads[{-.1, .1}], 
     Arrow[{Offset[{0, off2 - 50}, p1], Offset[{0, off2 - 50}, p2]}]}];
```

Diagrama

```
Show[{sup1, sup2, barra, f1, dim1, dim2, dim3},
  Axes - >{True, False},
  ImageSize -> Full,
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[3], FontSize -> 20]]
```

I am wanting to create something like this:

[image]

Comment: i don't think that Mathematica is the right tool for the job here. Consider using a vector graphics program instead. I use the free [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

Comment: I regularly make my illustrations to scientific papers with Mma more or less like you did it above. Technically my illustrations are comparable in complexity with your image, or (sometimes) more complex. So, I do not see here any problem. On the other hand, there is no special function(s) for that. One idea to simplify/accselerate the drawing would be to wrap the whole image by the Manipulate statement and search dynamically for, say, coordinates of the elements of your drawing. You might do it still faster by using a locator.

Comment: @MarcoB I beg to differ. It is/would be very useful to have that capability in Mathematica. Automating dimensioning can save a lot of time for repetitive tasks.

Comment: Then the way is to proceed as I am doing. Would you have any idea using manipulate or locator? I'm not looking for the perfect solution, but some first steps ...

Comment: @MarcosB Already make use of such vector graphics program. I'm just exploring the possibilities of Mathematica software.

Comment: I was thinking something like: `dimension[endpoint1_,endpoint2_,baseoffset_]:=...`

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in function specifically for this, but [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) does have FigBracket (see Examples-Diagrams.nb in its documentation).  Warning: SciDraw has a learning curve. It is not easy to lift out FigBracket and use it in standard Mathematica graphics.  You'd have to use it in SciDraw figures instead.

Comment: What about DrawingTools? For automatic approach `RegionBounds` and friends may be of use.

Comment: @Kuba the problem is that if one wants to make changes. So it is best to have this done using code, so it is automated. This is not an easy thing to do. Tikz, which is specialized for graphics, does not do dimensions. Doing automatic dimensions is a very very hard problem. Half of the code in CAD application is related to dimension software for engineering drawing. For example, if you want to change length of a line,whath should happen to the dimensions attached to it? etc... This is all automated in CAD engineering software. This is not trivial at all to do.

Comment: When I did something like the above in the question in Mathematica, I had to draw the whole thing using Graphics. But was very time consuming. Here is the page. The diagram are done using Mathematica Graphics2D code. [HW](http://12000.org/my_courses/univ_wisconsin_madison/spring_2014/EMA_523_flight_dynamics_and_control/inse3.htm#x6-50001) Lots of Arrow commands and Line commands :)

Comment: There are the GraphicsTools and MechanicsTools Packages (link: http://cit.blinn.edu/physics/Mathematica/index.html ) that provide some   
shared Graphics tools for physics diagrams, See also the library link: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9044/

Comment: [This](http://mechanismsrobotics.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/data/Journals/JMROA6/935088/jmr_008_03_034501_f002.png) is an example of some 3D-dimensioning I did with *Mathematica*, which is based on macros/functions and not just bare-bones hard-coded `Graphics3D`. The code is not packaged (yet) though. Having a nice version with 2D/3D capability should be very cool.

Comment: I did exactly this question to the comments presented possible solutions. I work daily with SolidWorks software and as I am inexperienced with Mathematica software and I was thinking of using it, similarly to SolidWorks for this to meet my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you an example of using the locator within your image try this:

```
      p1 = {0, 0}(*Ponto1 de apoio da barra*); p2 = {1, 
  0}(*Ponto2 de apoio da barra*);
barra = Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], Line[{p1, p2}]}];
hsup = .08(*Altura do suporte*); sup1 = 
 Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.34], Thickness[0.005](*Espessura do Suporte*), 
   Line[{{p1[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}, {p1[[1]] + hsup/2, -hsup}, 
     p1, {p1[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}}]}];
sup2 = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.34], 
    Thickness[0.005](*Espessura do Suporte*), 
    Line[{{p2[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}, {p2[[1]] + hsup/2, -hsup}, 
      p2, {p2[[1]] - hsup/2, -hsup}}]}];
posx = 0.2(*Porcentagem relativa ao comprimento da barra*)*(p2[[1]] - 
     p1[[1]])(*Comprimento da barra*);
f1 = Graphics[{Red, Thickness[0.02](*Espessura da seta*), 
    Arrowheads[hf1/3], 
    Arrow[{{posx, hf1 = 0.25(*Altura da seta*)}, {posx, p1[[2]]}}]}];
dim1 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], 
    Line[{Offset[{0, off1 = 20}, p1], Offset[{0, off2 = 400}, p1]}]}];
dim2 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], 
    Line[{Offset[{0, off1}, p2], Offset[{0, off2}, p2]}]}];
dim3 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], Arrowheads[{-.1, .1}], 
    Arrow[{Offset[{0, off2 - 50}, p1], Offset[{0, off2 - 50}, p2]}]}];
```

Here are your definitions, and I am playing with the positioning of a red arrow using the locators below:

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {0.5, 0.5}, pt2 = {0.5, 0.7}},
 f1 = Graphics[{Red, Thickness[0.02](*Espessura da seta*), 
    Arrowheads[hf1/3], Dynamic[Arrow[{pt1, pt2}]]}];
 Column[{
   Show[{sup1, sup2, barra, f1, dim1, dim2, dim3,
     Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic[pt1]], Locator[Dynamic[pt2]]}]     
     }, Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> Full, 
    AxesStyle -> 
     Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[3], FontSize -> 20]],
   Button["Print it", Column[{Print[pt1], Print[pt2]}]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

After you have positioned the arrow, press the button and the coordinates will appear below the image. Copy-paste them instead of pt1 and pt2 into the code. Revove the Dynamic statement around the Arrow statement. When the positioning of all elements is terminated, remove unnecessary elements from the code.

Here is the realization with the Manipulate statement:

```
     Manipulate[

     f1 = Graphics[{Red, Thickness[0.02](*Espessura da seta*), 
        Arrowheads[hf1/3], Arrow[{Scaled[{x, y}], Scaled[{z, t}]}]}, 
       PlotRange -> {0, 0.5}];

     Column[{
       Show[{f1, sup1, sup2, barra, dim1, dim2, dim3

         }, Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> 350, 
        AxesStyle -> 
         Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[3], FontSize -> 20]],

       }], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}

 ]
```

[image]

Position the arrow with the sliders. After it is done, copy-paste the figures from the text fields of the Manipulate panel into the Arrow statement. Start positioning other elements of the figure. After the image is finished, remove all elements of the manipulate statement.

Have fun!